# newSession from a Parent Session

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When we create new session using `newSession()`, would the new session inherits all config properties set from parent session?

As per the [spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.newSession.html), `newSession()` returns a new `SparkSession` as new session, that has separate `SQLConf`, but shared `SparkContext` and table cache. Could not follow the difference between `SQLConf` and `SparkContext` in this context.

Performed below tests on Databricks, it seems newSession is not inhering any existing configs from parent session. In that case, what is the meaning of line mentioned in the doc - *"new session, that has separate `SQLConf`, but shared `SparkContext` and table cache"*?

```py
# Session-1

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark_session_1 = SparkSession.builder.appName('app_name').config("spark.sql.sources.default", "parquet").getOrCreate()
spark_session_1.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "5000")

print(spark_session_1.conf.get("spark.sql.sources.default"))    # parquet (note: default val is 'delta')
print(spark_session_1.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")) # 5000
```

```py
# Session-2

spark_session_2 = spark_session_1.newSession()

print(spark_session_2.conf.get("spark.sql.sources.default"))     # delta
print(spark_session_2.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions"))  # 200
```

```py
# Session-3

spark_session_3 = spark_session_1.newSession()
spark_session_3.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "333")

print(spark_session_3.conf.get("spark.sql.sources.default"))    # delta
print(spark_session_3.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")) # 333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing makes sense, because both of the config values you're looking at:

- `spark.sql.sources.default`
- `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`

are `SQLConf` configuration values (notice that they start with `spark.sql`). You can see that in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L625-L632). That means that it makes sense that when creating a new session using `newSession` you don't inherit those configuration values. Because you don't share the same `SQLConf`!

For the difference between a `SparkContext` and `SQLConf`:

- a [`SparkContext`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.html) *represents the connection to a Spark cluster, and can be used to create RDD and broadcast variables on that cluster*.
- `SQLConf` is a class that enables setting and getting of `spark.sql` configuration parameters

But what is the use of this then? Well, it makes it possible to use different SQL configuration values in the same `SparkContext`. This means that in a single application on a single cluster, you can have multiple DataFrames with different SQL properties which gives some flexibility if that is needed in your application.

Comment: makes sense. Are the parameters such as "spark.executor.instances" / "spark.executor.cores" , SQLConf?

Comment: No those aren't. You can simply remember that if the config parameter does not start with `spark.sql`, it won't be a SQLConf parameter :)

Comment: lastly on this, so if `spark.executor.instances` / `spark.executor.cores` are not `SQLConf`, are they inherited to child sessions? I tried perform the test similar to above where I set `spark.executor.cores` to 5 in parent session (`spark_session_1`) and tried to get value in child session (`spark_session_2`) using `print(spark_session_2.conf.get("spark.executor.cores"))`, but getting error - `java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.executor.cores`

Comment: Those are indeed inherited to child sessions: they are part of the `SparkContext` configuration values, which is shared over all sessions. To access those values, you can retrieve them like so: `spark_session_1.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()`. You'll only find those configuration values in there if you set them to be different to their default values. So if you add `--conf spark.executor.cores=2` to your `spark-submit` or `pyspark` command, you'll find them in there.

Comment: thank you. found on similar note, please would it be possible to  clarify - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77847292/retrieving-the-specific-configurations?noredirect=1#comment137246525_77847292

Comment: I've answered that question, have a look to see whether that clears things up :)