# Retrieving the specific configurations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have not specified any spark properties in my application and going with default values. How do we find the specific value of a specific spark properties being used?

In below case, why we are not able to find value of `spark.executor.cores` and running into error?

- On running the below, getting  the error message - org.apache.spark.SparkNoSuchElementException: [SQL_CONF_NOT_FOUND] The SQL config "spark.executor.cores" cannot be found. Please verify that the config exists.

  - Same error for spark.executor.instances.

```
print(spark.conf.get("spark.executor.cores"))
```

- On running the below, I get a value of 200

```
print(spark.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions"))
```

- On running the below, do not see both of the above configurations mentioned in the result.

```
print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll())
```

Comment: To see the parameters set, default or user set values, run the application and go to the spark UI and check the Environments tab that will list all the spark parameters being used.

Comment: thank you. I get that, trying to follow how to check as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encountering 2 different types of configuration parameters that are confusing you here:

- **SparkContext config parameters**: these are generic to your cluster. You can access those by using `spark.sparkContext.getConf().get("my-conf"))`. They are generic to your application, whether or not you're using Spark SQL.
- **Spark SQL config parameters**: configuration parameters that start with `spark.sql.`. These are relevant when you're using Spark SQL (when using DataFrames for example). You can access these by using `spark.conf.get("my-sql-conf")`.

Now we know this, we understand why

Let's answer the 3 following questions:

**Why does `print(spark.conf.get("spark.executor.cores"))` return nothing?**

`spark.executor.cores` is not a SQL configuration parameter so is not accessible with `spark.conf.get()`.

**Why does `print(spark.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions"))` return 200?**

Since this config param starts with `spark.sql`, it IS a SQL config parameter. So it's accessible with `spark.conf.get()`.

**But why don't you find `spark.executor.cores` in the output of the following command?**

```py
print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll())
```

The reason why is that you probably started your SparkContext by explicitly setting that configuration parameter. In that case, they don't show up in this list that is the output of `.getAll()`. Of course, they do have values but the value will just be the default value.

For the following code, I will be using `spark.sparkContext.getConf().get()` instead of `.getAll()` but they essentially do the same. `.get()` just gives the value of a specific config param.

If I start up a pyspark shell without explicitly setting that configuration parameter, I get the following:

```py
pyspark

# Wait until the pyspark REPL is up and running
>>> print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().get("spark.executor.cores"))
None
```

If I start up a pyspark shell and explicitly set the `spark.executor.cores` value, I get the following:

```py
pyspark --conf spark.executor.cores=3

# Wait until the pyspark REPL is up and running
>>> print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().get("spark.executor.cores"))
3
```

### Conclusion

There are 2 things to remember here:

- SparkContext config params != Spark SQL config parameters
- The output of `spark.sparkContext.getConf().get()` does not always return a value for a configuration parameter. For some configuration parameters, it only returns a value if you explicitly set that value.

Comment: I'm using Databricks, not setting any params explicitly. Just tested, as you pointed out when we dont set any params explicitly,    `print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().get("spark.executor.cores"))` returns None. Also don't see a mention in`spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()` . In such case, how can we check default value being used by Spark?

Comment: sorry for the follow up, would you be able to clarify please?

Comment: Ah damn I lost sight of your comment, sorry! Here on stackoverflow we try to keep the scope of questions focused, so that future readers can easily find exactly what they are looking for. Since I feel your original question was answered, I propose that you make a new question post? You can send me the link to your new question here in the comment. I'll already start looking for your answer :)

Comment: no problem, all good for learning. Posted a question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77872130/retrieving-the-default-configurations

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong syntax for printing these config, please use the below

```
print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().get("spark.executor.instances"))
print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().get("spark.executor.cores"))
```