# Retrieving the default configurations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

As per the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77847292/retrieving-the-specific-configurations) , the output of `spark.sparkContext.getConf().get()` does not always return a value for a configuration parameter. For some configuration parameters, it only returns a value if we have explicitly set that value.

I'm using Databricks/Dataproc, not setting any params explicitly. When we dont set any params explicitly, `print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().get("spark.executor.cores"))` returns None. Also don't see a mention of `spark.executor.cores`/`spark.executor.instances` in `spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()` . In such cases, how can we check default value for a config being used by Spark?

Comment: you could check the configs on SparkUI.

Comment: You can check the [spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) for default values

Comment: any approach where can get defaults programmatically like spark.conf.get() or getAll() , other than SparkUI or docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62526302/15405732) proposes:

```py
import json
import urllib.request

from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
u = sc.uiWebUrl + "/api/v1/applications/" + sc.applicationId + "/allexecutors"
with urllib.request.urlopen(u) as url:
    executors_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

Now, this `executors_data` is a python list (one element per executor) that contains a bunch of information about your executors. It looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "driver",
    "hostPort": "XXX",
    "isActive": "True",
    "rddBlocks": 0,
    "memoryUsed": 0,
    "diskUsed": 0,
    "totalCores": 16,
    "maxTasks": 16,
    "activeTasks": 0,
    "failedTasks": 0,
    "completedTasks": 0,
    "totalTasks": 0,
    "totalDuration": 26786,
    "totalGCTime": 21,
    "totalInputBytes": 0,
    "totalShuffleRead": 0,
    "totalShuffleWrite": 0,
    "isBlacklisted": "False",
    "maxMemory": 455501414,
    "addTime": "2024-01-25T10:34:44.08 9GMT",
    "executorLogs": {},
    "memoryMetrics": {
      "usedOnHeapStorageMemory": 0,
      "usedOffHeapStorageMemory": 0,
      "totalOnHeapStorageMemory": 455501414,
      "totalOffHeapStorageMemory": 0
    },
    "blacklistedInStages": [],
    "peakM emoryMetrics": {
      "JVMHeapMemory": 148771744,
      "JVMOffHeapMemory": 68732808,
      "OnHeapExecutionMemory": 0,
      "OffHeapExecutionMemory": 0,
      "OnHeapStorageMemory": 0,
      "OffHeapStorageMemory": 0,
      "OnHeapUnifiedMemory": 0,
      " OffHeapUnifiedMemory": 0,
      "DirectPoolMemory": 16385,
      "MappedPoolMemory": 0,
      "ProcessTreeJVMVMemory": 0,
      "ProcessTreeJVMRSSMemory": 0,
      "ProcessTreePythonVMemory": 0,
      "ProcessTreePythonRSSMemory": 0,
      "ProcessTreeO therVMemory": 0,
      "ProcessTreeOtherRSSMemory": 0,
      "MinorGCCount": 5,
      "MinorGCTime": 21,
      "MajorGCCount": 0,
      "MajorGCTime": 0,
      "TotalGCTime": 21
    },
    "attributes": {},
    "resources": {},
    "resourceProfileId": 0,
    "isExclu ded": "False",
    "excludedInStages": []
  }
]
```

You'll notice that in my case I only have 1 executor (which is the driver). This is because I'm executing this on a pyspark shell with `--master local` so that turns your driver into the only executor. In case you have an actual cluster where the driver and executors are separate JVM processes, you can filter the executors_data list like so:

```py
executors_data = [x for x in executors_data if x["id"] != "driver"]
```

To extract info out of this list, you can do things like the following:

```py
num_executors = len(executors_data)
total_cores = sum([x["totalCores"] for x in executors_data])
```

Comment: @koedit would you be able to look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77960342/minimum-time-for-each-unique-non-null-value-of-each-column ? thank you.