# minimum time for each unique non null value of each column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to transform a data in a dataframe using PySpark and generate results as json lines. required transformations are as below:

- group by id, collect `distinct` values of each columns  (excluding `id` and `day_time`)  and minimum of `day_time` for each unique value,  into an array under the 'details' field.
- value for `key` within `details`: unique non null values for all other columns  (excluding 'id' and 'day_time')
- value for `timestamp` within `details`: for each value  of 'key', minimum of `day_time` field within the `id` group
- If all values within a column for a specific group are null, ignore and dont add to result (ex: `reference` for group id 1 or `activities`, `type`, `is_batch` for group id 2)

**Input Data:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType, TimestampType, BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_timestamp
from datetime import datetime

# Define the schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("day_time", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("country", StringType(), True),
    StructField("reference", StringType(), True),
    StructField("activities", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("type", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("is_batch", StringType(), True),
    StructField("is_stream", StringType(), True)
])

# Sample data
data = [("1", datetime.strptime("2024-01-08T13:14:41", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), "US", None, ["fun"], ["r1"], None, "FALSE"),
        ("1", datetime.strptime("2024-01-08T13:14:42", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), "US", None, ["action","adventure"], None, None, "TRUE"),
        ("1", datetime.strptime("2024-01-08T13:14:43", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), "US", None , None ,    ["r2"], "FALSE", "TRUE"),
        ("1", datetime.strptime("2024-01-08T13:14:44", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), "US", None, ["action","adventure"], ["r2"]  ,"FALSE" ,"TRUE"),
        ("2", datetime.strptime("2024-01-09T00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), "US", "xyz",  None,    None, None, "FALSE")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.show()
```

**Expected result below:** please ignore comment starting #, mentioned only to better clarify how columns are represented in `details`. Currently Im thinking of a approach where I group each column (except day_time) with id, take minimum of day_time as timestamp value, store as separate column, later concatenate all under `details` and finally write as json.

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "details" :
    [
        {"key":"US",timestamp:"2024-01-08T13:14:41Z"},  # for column 'country'
        
        {"key":"fun",timestamp:"2024-01-08T13:14:41Z"},{"key":"action",timestamp:"2024-01-08T13:14:42Z"}, {"key":"adventure",timestamp:"2024-01-08T13:14:42Z"}, # for column 'activities'

        {"key":"r1",timestamp:"2024-01-08T13:14:41Z"}, {"key":"r2",timestamp:"2024-01-08T13:14:43Z"}, # for column 'type'

        {"key":"FALSE",timestamp:"2024-01-08T13:14:43Z"}, # for column 'is_batch'

        {"key":"FALSE",timestamp:"2024-01-08T13:14:41Z"}, {"key":"TRUE",timestamp:"2024-01-08T13:14:42Z"} # for column 'is_stream'

    ]

},

{
    "id": "2",
    "details" :
    [
        {"key":"US",timestamp:"2024-01-09T00:00:00Z"},  # for column 'country'
        
        {"key":"xyz",timestamp:"2024-01-09T00:00:00Z"}, # for column 'reference'

        {"key":"FALSE",timestamp:"2024-01-09T00:00:00Z"} # for column 'is_stream'

    ]

}
```

**Transform** : Below code generates data as below for one of the column `is_stream`.

```
{"id":"1","details":[{"key":"FALSE","timestamp":"2024-01-08T13:14:41.000Z"},{"key":"TRUE","timestamp":"2024-01-08T13:14:42.000Z"}]}
{"id":"2","details":[{"key":"FALSE","timestamp":"2024-01-09T00:00:00.000Z"}]}
```

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import min,collect_list

filtered_df = df.filter(df['is_stream'].isNotNull())

min_timestamp_df = filtered_df.groupBy("id", "is_stream").agg(min("day_time").alias("timestamp"))

json_string = min_timestamp_df.selectExpr("id", "struct(is_stream as key, timestamp) as details ") \
   .groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("details").alias("details"))

# result = json_string.toJSON().collect()
json_string.show(truncate=False)
json_string.write.json("s3://final_data/")
```

**Question** : Is there any way I can do this in one iteration for all columns of all data types including list or any better way instead of having to perform groupBy twice?